# Why does steam store large amounts of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, covalent-compounds, hydrogen-bond, gas-phase-chemistry

We all know that steam can be used to perform mechanical work and steam has a high capacity for energy storage. But why does steam have such high energy capacity?
I tried searching for answers on the net but couldn't find any. So I came up with my own theory:

> Steam is gaseous form of water and water is made up of H2O molecules.
> Since the molecule consists of hydrogen, there will be a presence of hydrogen bonds between every two hyrogens of every two neighbouring molecules. Steam is formed when these bonds are broken and each H2O molecule moves further apart from their neighbouring molecules. But hydrogen bonds are strong. Thus in order to break these bonds, large amounts of energy must be supplied to liquid water inorder to convert it to steam. And this large amounts energy is thus stored in steam. Thus making steam a large energy capacitor.

Is my theory right?

Comment: Yes. Your theory makes sense.Why not ?

Comment: What do you mean by “energy capacity”? Most liquids can be evaporated in order to perform mechanical work via the volume expansion of the phase change

Comment: @Andrew energy storage capacity compared to other liquids that donot possess hydrogen bonds?

Comment: Consider 2 mechanical analogies: 1/ A ball laying on the top of a heap above the flat. 2/ A ball laying on the flat next to a hole. Which scenario reminds you the relation of energies of water and vapor ? Does vapor store big amount of energy like 1/, or is it rather a big amount of energy is released, forming a liquid, like in 2/ ? // And yes, the high value of water heat of evaporation is caused by energy needed to break hydrogen bonds.

Comment: So do you mean the enthalpy of vaporization? or maybe the specific heat capacity? Neither of those are directly related to the mechanical work that can be done by expansion, although they are relevant to the process.